# How can I get all the classes that have a certain attribute in php 8?

Tags: php, attributes, php-8

I have several classes with a certain attribute, how can I get all the classes that have it?

```
#[Attribute]
class MyAttribute {}

#[MyAttribute]
class Foo
{
}

#[MyAttribute]
class Bar
{
}
```

Have some ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to search through your codebase? Or otherwise what do you mean by "get" the classes, exactly?

Comment: @ADyson yes in my codebase

Answer (score 1):

You can make with php Reflection, or just by a bash command `grep '\#\[YourAttributeName\]' -A1 -r projectfolder | grep Class | awk '{print $2}'`

---

Here is the php way.

First use the `get_declared_classes()` to get all declared class. Then you can make the `ReflectionClass` on each class. Then check if the `ReflectionClass` has the attribute.

```
$allClasses = get_declared_classes();

foreach ($allClasses as $className) {
    $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $attributes = $reflectionClass->getAttributes();

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->getName() === $attributeName) {
            $classesWithAttribute[] = $className;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```